# run pm2 with ES modules

Tags: javascript, pm2

How can i use pm2 in combination with a package based on ES Module (type:"module")
I looked into similar Questions without any useful help (some say it does not work on windows, but i am using linux)

I always receive the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /opt/app/server/lib/src/index.js not supported.
0|any| Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

My ecosystem.config.js looks like:

```
const os = require('os');
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        port        : 3000,
        name        : "any",
        script      : "lib/src/index.js",
        watch       : true,           
        instances   : os.cpus().length,
        exec_mode   : 'fork',         
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
        }
    }]
}
```

index.js is a ES module using "import" syntax. How can i tell pm2 that is should use this way of importing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve this you can create an intermediary CommonJS module which loads your application from ESModule. It's possible with `import` function available in commonJs modules.

This is how might this look:

- `ecosystem.config.js`
- `lib/src/index.cjs` CommonJS entry point (for PM2).
- `lib/src/index.js` ESModule entry point (for ESM-compatible tools).
- `lib/src/app.js` Application code.

`ecosystem.config.js`:

```js
const os = require('os');
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        port        : 3000,
        name        : "any",
        script      : "lib/src/index.cjs", //  CommonJS
        watch       : true,           
        instances   : os.cpus().length,
        exec_mode   : 'fork',         
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
        }
    }]
}
```

`lib/src/index.js`:

```js
import {app} from './app.js'

app()
```

`lib/src/index.cjs`:

```js
import('./app.js') //  There is import function available in CommonJS
.then(({app}) => {
 app()
})
```

`lib/src/app.js`:

```js
import {hello} from './greet.js'

export function app() {
  console.log(hello('World'))
}
```

`lib/src/greet.js`:

```js
export function hello(name) {
  return `Hello, ${name}!`
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Is there an easy way to use esm import within app.js when using CommonJs entry Point with PM2? For instance in app.js -> import {func} from "./other.js". I have not tried yet, but i guess it will be the same error again. Ill try tomorrow but maybe you know that.

Comment: If export works then import would work too. I've updated example with such import.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works

Answer (score 14):

renaming `ecosystem.config.js` to `ecosystem.config.cjs` worked for me